# Command with KEYPOS and SEP like sort, but for removing or moving instead of sorting?

Tags: regex, string, sorting, vim, move

Example:

```
1;Cristiano Ronaldo;Portugal;88;121;0.73;'03-;Manchester United, Real Madrid
```

Sort can help me seperate fiels by the `-t` `;` tag. then `-k3,3` can help me select the third field (`88`). Now let's say I wan to delete this string (`88`) instead of sorting out, what command can help me? Is there also a command that can help me move the strings from position `88` to position `121` and vice versa?

It sounds crazy to me if I would have to use regular expressions with substitute :s everytime (espcially for moving things) when sort can divide fields by strings

Comment: Well there's AWK.

Comment: `cut -d ';' -f 1-3,5-9`